# How to change the text color of specific word of textview in ios5

Tags: ios, uitextview

How to change the text color of particular word of textview text in ios5.I have implemented an app in that I displayed the mangalAshtak shlok in textview .It also has play button which plays audio file of mangal ashtak.Now I want to synchronise audio file with textview .I I have implemented this using NSMutableAttributedString in ios 6 as below

```
   if(seconds>=42 && seconds<43) 
   {
    NSMutableAttributedString * string = [[NSMutableAttributedString   alloc]initWithString:self.textView.text]; 
   NSString *word= [shlok2 objectAtIndex:0]; //array shlok 2 contains each word of shlok       
   NSLog(@"%@",word); 
   NSRange range=[self.textView.text rangeOfString:word]; 
  [string addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor whiteColor] range:range]; 
   [self.textView setAttributedText:string]; 
   [textView setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:16]]; 
}
```

using above code it changed the color of text with audio file .In play button action I checked the current timing of AVAudioPlayer object & changed the respective text .But in ios 5 it doesn't work?

Answer (score 2):

Support for attributed strings in UIKit classes like `UITextView` was only added in iOS 6. To do this on earlier systems you will have to draw the strings yourself using Core Text or a framework like [DTCoreText](https://github.com/Cocoanetics/DTCoreText).

Comment: I have downloaded the DTCoreText Framework from GitHub & tried to run but I got the error like  'DTUtils.h' file not found.Please help how to use that framework in my project